# Web view scroll lags

Tags: android, webview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a layout in which a web view is lie inside a nested scrollview with coordinator Layout. Where I feed data to webview from webservice and apply customize css according to my layout. But When I scroll my view It lags a lots and more when there is image in web data. How to solve this.?

I tried to disable webview nested scroll but wouldn't helped.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mWebView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    } else {
        mParentView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    }
```